# Apply a function to each row in a data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, sapply

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [how to apply a function to every row of a matrix (or a data frame) in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236368/how-to-apply-a-function-to-every-row-of-a-matrix-or-a-data-frame-in-r)
>
> [R - how to call apply-like function on each row of dataframe with multiple arguments from each row of the df](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15059076/r-how-to-call-apply-like-function-on-each-row-of-dataframe-with-multiple-argum)

I want to apply a function to each row in a data frame, however, R applies it to each column by default. How do I force it otherwise?

```
> a = as.data.frame(list(c(1,2,3),c(10,0,6)),header=T)
> a
  c.1..2..3. c.10..0..6.
1          1          10
2          2           0
3          3           6
> sapply(a,min)
 c.1..2..3. c.10..0..6. 
          1           0
```

I wanted something like

```
1   2
2   0
3   3
```

Comment: I saw lapply doc said it returns a list, and sapply doc said it is a user friendly version that returns an object of the appropriate type.

Comment: `lapply()` and `sapply()` operate over the *components* of a vector. That vector can be an atomic vector (e.g. `1:10`) or a list. For a list, it applies the function to each component of the list. A data frame is a special case of a list, where the "columns" are the components, hence `lapply()` and `sapply()` work on the "columns" of a data frame.

Comment: It doesn't say that; it says, "sapply is a user-friendly version of lapply by default returning a vector or matrix if appropriate."

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You want `apply` (see the docs for it).  `apply(var,1,fun)` will apply to rows,  `apply(var,2,fun)` will apply to columns.

```
> apply(a,1,min)
[1] 1 0 3
```

Comment: What if I wanted the minimum from a given column? say column 2.

Comment: @Selvam, `min(a[,2])` -- but you should probably read through some of the introductory R material (such as http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.html#Array-indexing ) -- that's a pretty basic question.

Comment: This doesn't exactly answer the original questions.  `apply()` will try to convert the data.frame into a matrix (see the help docs).  If it does not gracefully convert due to mixed data types, I'm not quite sure what would result.

Comment: @SheaParkes If you don't need the strings in the function, just do apply(a[NumericColNames],1,min).

Comment: @SheaParkes I believe it will convert all data types to the "lowest common denominator", which usually ends up being simply character.