# Applying a function to every row of a table using dplyr?

Tags: r, plyr, dplyr

When working with `plyr` I often found it useful to use `adply` for scalar functions that I have to apply to each and every row.

e.g.

```
data(iris)
library(plyr)
head(
     adply(iris, 1, transform , Max.Len= max(Sepal.Length,Petal.Length))
    )
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species Max.Len
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa     5.1
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa     4.9
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa     4.7
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa     4.6
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa     5.0
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa     5.4
```

Now I'm using `dplyr` more, I'm wondering if there is a tidy/natural way to do this? As this is **NOT** what I want:

```
library(dplyr)
head(
     mutate(iris, Max.Len= max(Sepal.Length,Petal.Length))
    )
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species Max.Len
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa     7.9
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa     7.9
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa     7.9
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa     7.9
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa     7.9
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa     7.9
```

Comment: i recently asked if there was an equivalent of `mdply` in dplyr, and hadley suggested that they might be brewing something based on `do`. I guess it would also work here.

Comment: Eventually dplyr will have something like `rowwise()` which would group by each individual row

Comment: @hadley thx, shouldn't it just behave like `adply` when you don't use a grouping though? as its closely integrated function is called `group_by` NOT `split_by`

Comment: @StephenHenderson no, because you also need some way to operate on the table as a whole.

Comment: Related post: [Call apply-like function on each row of dataframe with multiple arguments from each row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15059076)

Comment: I know this is a really old question,  but iris %>% mutate(Max.Len=pmax(Sepal.Length,Sepal.Width) )  works also

Comment: @HowYaDoing Yes but that method doesn't generalise. There is no psum, pmean or pmedian for instance.

Answer (score 229, accepted):

As of dplyr 0.2 (I think) `rowwise()` is implemented, so the answer to this problem becomes:

```
iris %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(Max.Len= max(Sepal.Length,Petal.Length))
```

### Non `rowwise` alternative

Five years (!) later this answer still gets a lot of traffic. Since it was given, `rowwise` is increasingly not recommended, although lots of people seem to find it intuitive. Do yourself a favour and go through Jenny Bryan's [Row-oriented workflows in R with the tidyverse](https://github.com/jennybc/row-oriented-workflows) material to get a good handle on this topic.

The most straightforward way I have found is based on one of Hadley's examples using `pmap`:

```
iris %>% 
  mutate(Max.Len= purrr::pmap_dbl(list(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length), max))
```

Using this approach, you can give an arbitrary number of arguments to the function  (`.f`) inside `pmap`.

`pmap` is a good conceptual approach because it reflects the fact that when you're doing row wise operations you're actually working with tuples from a list of vectors (the columns in a dataframe).

Comment: I've changed this (from the above) to the ideal answer as I think this is the intended usage.

Comment: is it possible to add the values of a dynamically formed datatframe? So in this data frame the column names are not known. I am able to add if column names are known.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28807266/row-wise-cor-on-subset-of-columns-using-dplyrmutate just found the answer. In this they are using correlation instead of sum. But same concept.

Comment: If it does not work, make sure you are actually using dplyr::mutate not plyr::mutate - drove me nuts

Comment: Thanks YAK, this bit me too.  If you include both `plyr` and `dplyr` packages, you are almost certainly using the wrong `mutate` unless you explicitly provide scope `dplyr::mutate`.

Comment: Be cautious using this approach as `mutate()` can slow down dramatically given large numbers of groups. Groups in the order of 10^5 can mean mutation takes minutes instead of microseconds. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/MilesMcBain/d08cc4f675e00edf806b7f5f20f29ea2).

Comment: If you are reading this for the future: **consider whether your problem can be vectorised first**... For example here, there is already a vectorised `max` function called `pmax`, so using `rowwise` is doubly inefficent: more to type and more time to process. See mnel's answer below for the general case when no vectorised function readily exists.

Comment: It does not work with the output of the function to be apply by row is something more complex like a list. What is suggested to use in that case?

Comment: @ErickChacon I recommend asking that as a separate question

Comment: Thanks so much - I've been banging my head against this issue for a while. It does seem odd that a) this isnt the default behaviour for something built for data frames? b) why would it be slower - shouldn't rowwise mean less processing?

Comment: This function is currently in "questioning" stage of lifecycle. https://www.tidyverse.org/lifecycle/#questioning

Comment: you do not need `rowwise` to `mutate(Max.Len= max(Sepal.Length,Petal.Length))`, and it will also have the side effect of grouping and outputting a tibble, instead of a data.frame.

Comment: @d8aninja have you compared the output with and without? It makes a big different to what `max` returns

Comment: @alexwhan Hmm.. I'm really not liking the `purrr::pmap_dbl` method. It's a real conceptual leap. Wouldn't want to teach that in software carpentry ;)

Comment: @StephenHenderson agreed it's a challenge. I've now really come around to it conceptually, but it depends on an understanding of what's actually happening. `rowwise` feels very natural to new users in my experience

Comment: I'm sure this answer will continue to get lots of traffic...It's worth mentioning, as of mid-2020, `rowwise()` is now accepted (and recommended) in dplyr 1.0.0, and will likely stick around. Hadley was convinced of it's utility and intuitiveness over the purrr solutions. See the [official documentation](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/rowwise.html)

Comment: How to give the names of the variables in a *tidyselect* way for the `pmap` approach?

Comment: "although lots of people seem to find it intuitive" <-- It's R's mission to do the opposite.

Answer (score 24):

The idiomatic approach will be to create an appropriately vectorised function.

`R` provide `pmax` which is suitable here, however it also provides `Vectorize` as a wrapper for `mapply` to allow you to create a vectorised arbitrary version of an arbitrary function.

```
library(dplyr)
# use base R pmax (vectorized in C)
iris %>% mutate(max.len = pmax(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length))
# use vectorize to create your own function
# for example, a horribly inefficient get first non-Na value function
# a version that is not vectorized
coalesce <- function(a,b) {r <- c(a[1],b[1]); r[!is.na(r)][1]}
# a vectorized version
Coalesce <- Vectorize(coalesce, vectorize.args = c('a','b'))
# some example data
df <- data.frame(a = c(1:5,NA,7:10), b = c(1:3,NA,NA,6,NA,10:8))
df %>% mutate(ab =Coalesce(a,b))
```

Note that implementing the vectorization in C / C++ will be faster, but there isn't a `magicPony` package that will write the function for you.

Comment: thx, this is a great answer, is excellent general R style -idiomatic as you say, but I don't think its really addressing my question whether there is a `dplyr` way... as it would be simpler without dplyr  e.g. `with(df, Coalesce(a,b))` Perhaps, that's a kind of answer though  - don't use `dplyr` for that?

Comment: Have to admit I double checked that there isn't a ```magicPony``` package. Too bad

Answer (score 22):

You need to group by row:

```
iris %>% group_by(1:n()) %>% mutate(Max.Len= max(Sepal.Length,Petal.Length))
```

This is what the `1` did in `adply`.

Comment: It seems like there should be a simpler or "nicer" syntax.

Comment: @StephenHenderson, there may be, I'm not a `dplyr` expert.  Hopefully someone else will come along with something better.  Note I cleaned it up a bit with `1:n()`.

Comment: I suspect you are right, but I sort of feel like the default behaviour with no grouping should be like the `group_by(1:n())` behaviour. If no-one has any other ideas in the morning I'll tick yours ;)

Comment: Also, note that this is somewhat in contravention of documentation for `n`: "This function is implemented special for each data source and can only be used from within summarise.", though it seems to work.

Comment: Can you refer to Sepal.Length and Petal.Length by their index number in some way? If you have lots of variables did would be handy. Like ... Max.len = max( [c(1,3)] ) ?

Answer (score 19):

## Update 2017-08-03

After writing this, Hadley changed some stuff again. The functions that used to be in purrr are now in [a new mixed package called **purrrlyr**](https://github.com/hadley/purrrlyr), described as:

> purrrlyr contains some functions that lie at the intersection of purrr and dplyr. They have been removed from purrr in order to make the package lighter and because they have been replaced by other solutions in the tidyverse.

So, you will need to install + load that package to make the code below work.

## Original post

Hadley frequently changes his mind about what we should use, but I think we are supposed to switch to the functions in **purrr** to get the by row functionality. At least, they offer the same functionality and have almost the same interface as `adply` from **plyr**.

There are two related functions, `by_row` and `invoke_rows`. My understanding is that you use `by_row` when you want to loop over rows and add the results to the data.frame. `invoke_rows` is used when you loop over rows of a data.frame and pass each col as an argument to a function. We will only use the first.

## Examples

```
library(tidyverse)

iris %>% 
  by_row(..f = function(this_row) {
    browser()
  })
```

This lets us see the internals (so we can see what we are doing), which is the same as doing it with `adply`.

```
Called from: ..f(.d[[i]], ...)
Browse[1]> this_row
# A tibble: 1 × 5
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
         <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>  <fctr>
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
Browse[1]> Q
```

By default, `by_row` adds a list column based on the output:

```
iris %>% 
  by_row(..f = function(this_row) {
      this_row[1:4] %>% unlist %>% mean
  })
```

gives:

```
# A tibble: 150 × 6
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species      .out
          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>  <fctr>    <list>
1           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa <dbl [1]>
2           4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa <dbl [1]>
3           4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa <dbl [1]>
4           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa <dbl [1]>
5           5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa <dbl [1]>
6           5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa <dbl [1]>
7           4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3  setosa <dbl [1]>
8           5.0         3.4          1.5         0.2  setosa <dbl [1]>
9           4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2  setosa <dbl [1]>
10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1  setosa <dbl [1]>
# ... with 140 more rows
```

if instead we return a `data.frame`, we get a list with `data.frame`s:

```
iris %>% 
  by_row( ..f = function(this_row) {
    data.frame(
      new_col_mean = this_row[1:4] %>% unlist %>% mean,
      new_col_median = this_row[1:4] %>% unlist %>% median
    )
  })
```

gives:

```
# A tibble: 150 × 6
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species                 .out
          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>  <fctr>               <list>
1           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa <data.frame [1 × 2]>
2           4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa <data.frame [1 × 2]>
3           4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa <data.frame [1 × 2]>
4           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa <data.frame [1 × 2]>
5           5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa <data.frame [1 × 2]>
6           5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa <data.frame [1 × 2]>
7           4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3  setosa <data.frame [1 × 2]>
8           5.0         3.4          1.5         0.2  setosa <data.frame [1 × 2]>
9           4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2  setosa <data.frame [1 × 2]>
10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1  setosa <data.frame [1 × 2]>
# ... with 140 more rows
```

How we add the output of the function is controlled by the `.collate` param. There's three options: list, rows, cols. When our output has length 1, it doesn't matter whether we use rows or cols.

```
iris %>% 
  by_row(.collate = "cols", ..f = function(this_row) {
    this_row[1:4] %>% unlist %>% mean
  })

iris %>% 
  by_row(.collate = "rows", ..f = function(this_row) {
    this_row[1:4] %>% unlist %>% mean
  })
```

both produce:

```
# A tibble: 150 × 6
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species  .out
          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>  <fctr> <dbl>
1           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa 2.550
2           4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa 2.375
3           4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa 2.350
4           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa 2.350
5           5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa 2.550
6           5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa 2.850
7           4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3  setosa 2.425
8           5.0         3.4          1.5         0.2  setosa 2.525
9           4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2  setosa 2.225
10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1  setosa 2.400
# ... with 140 more rows
```

If we output a data.frame with 1 row, it matters only slightly which we use:

```
iris %>% 
  by_row(.collate = "cols", ..f = function(this_row) {
    data.frame(
      new_col_mean = this_row[1:4] %>% unlist %>% mean,
      new_col_median = this_row[1:4] %>% unlist %>% median
      )
  })

iris %>% 
  by_row(.collate = "rows", ..f = function(this_row) {
    data.frame(
      new_col_mean = this_row[1:4] %>% unlist %>% mean,
      new_col_median = this_row[1:4] %>% unlist %>% median
    )
  })
```

both give:

```
# A tibble: 150 × 8
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species  .row new_col_mean new_col_median
          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>  <fctr> <int>        <dbl>          <dbl>
1           5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa     1        2.550           2.45
2           4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa     2        2.375           2.20
3           4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa     3        2.350           2.25
4           4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa     4        2.350           2.30
5           5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa     5        2.550           2.50
6           5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa     6        2.850           2.80
7           4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3  setosa     7        2.425           2.40
8           5.0         3.4          1.5         0.2  setosa     8        2.525           2.45
9           4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2  setosa     9        2.225           2.15
10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1  setosa    10        2.400           2.30
# ... with 140 more rows
```

except that the second has the column called `.row` and the first does not.

Finally, if our output is longer than length 1 either as a `vector` or as a `data.frame` with rows, then it matters whether we use rows or cols for `.collate`:

```
mtcars[1:2] %>% by_row(function(x) 1:5)
mtcars[1:2] %>% by_row(function(x) 1:5, .collate = "rows")
mtcars[1:2] %>% by_row(function(x) 1:5, .collate = "cols")
```

produces, respectively:

```
# A tibble: 32 × 3
     mpg   cyl      .out
   <dbl> <dbl>    <list>
1   21.0     6 <int [5]>
2   21.0     6 <int [5]>
3   22.8     4 <int [5]>
4   21.4     6 <int [5]>
5   18.7     8 <int [5]>
6   18.1     6 <int [5]>
7   14.3     8 <int [5]>
8   24.4     4 <int [5]>
9   22.8     4 <int [5]>
10  19.2     6 <int [5]>
# ... with 22 more rows

# A tibble: 160 × 4
     mpg   cyl  .row  .out
   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int>
1     21     6     1     1
2     21     6     1     2
3     21     6     1     3
4     21     6     1     4
5     21     6     1     5
6     21     6     2     1
7     21     6     2     2
8     21     6     2     3
9     21     6     2     4
10    21     6     2     5
# ... with 150 more rows

# A tibble: 32 × 7
     mpg   cyl .out1 .out2 .out3 .out4 .out5
   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
1   21.0     6     1     2     3     4     5
2   21.0     6     1     2     3     4     5
3   22.8     4     1     2     3     4     5
4   21.4     6     1     2     3     4     5
5   18.7     8     1     2     3     4     5
6   18.1     6     1     2     3     4     5
7   14.3     8     1     2     3     4     5
8   24.4     4     1     2     3     4     5
9   22.8     4     1     2     3     4     5
10  19.2     6     1     2     3     4     5
# ... with 22 more rows
```

So, bottom line. If you want the `adply(.margins = 1, ...)` functionality, you can use `by_row`.

Comment: `by_row` is deprecated, calling it says to "use a combination of: tidyr::nest(); dplyr::mutate(); purrr::map()" https://github.com/hadley/purrrlyr/blob/eef6685db8841a246da28f0eb5e3ca1e9536cb8a/R/rows.R#L184

Comment: That's a lot of r's.

Answer (score 14):

Extending BrodieG's answer,

If the function returns more than one row, then instead of `mutate()`, `do()` must be used. Then to combine it back together, use `rbind_all()` from the `dplyr` package.

In `dplyr` version `dplyr_0.1.2`, using `1:n()` in the `group_by()` clause doesn't work for me. Hopefully [Hadley will implement `rowwise()`](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/270) soon.

```
iris %>%
    group_by(1:nrow(iris)) %>%
    do(do_fn) %>%
    rbind_all()
```

Testing the performance,

```
library(plyr)    # plyr_1.8.4.9000
library(dplyr)   # dplyr_0.8.0.9000
library(purrr)   # purrr_0.2.99.9000
library(microbenchmark)

d1_count <- 1000
d2_count <- 10

d1 <- data.frame(a=runif(d1_count))

do_fn <- function(row){data.frame(a=row$a, b=runif(d2_count))}
do_fn2 <- function(a){data.frame(a=a, b=runif(d2_count))}

op <- microbenchmark(
        plyr_version = plyr::adply(d1, 1, do_fn),
        dplyr_version = d1 %>%
            dplyr::group_by(1:nrow(d1)) %>%
            dplyr::do(do_fn(.)) %>%
            dplyr::bind_rows(),
        purrr_version = d1 %>% purrr::pmap_dfr(do_fn2),
        times=50)
```

it has the following results:

```
Unit: milliseconds
          expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
  plyr_version 1227.2589 1275.1363 1317.3431 1293.5759 1314.4266 1616.5449    50
 dplyr_version  977.3025 1012.6340 1035.9436 1025.6267 1040.5882 1449.0978    50
 purrr_version  609.5790  629.7565  643.8498  644.2505  656.1959  686.8128    50
```

This shows that the new `purrr` version is the fastest

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the great answer provided by @alexwhan, please keep in mind that you need to use `ungroup()` to avoid side effects.  This is because `rowwise()` is a grouping operation.

```
iris %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(Max.Len = max(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length))
```

will give you:

```
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species Max.Len
          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>     <dbl>
 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa      5.1
 2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa      4.9
 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa      4.7
 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa      4.6
 5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa      5  
 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa      5.4
 7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa      4.6
 8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa      5  
 9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa      4.4
10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa      4.9
```

Now let's assume that you need to continue with the `dplyr` pipe to add a `lead` to `Max.Len`:

```
iris %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(Max.Len = max(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length)) %>%
    mutate(Lead.Max.Len = lead(Max.Len))
```

This will produce:

```
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species Max.Len Lead.Max.Len
          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>     <dbl>        <dbl>
 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa      5.1           NA
 2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa      4.9           NA
 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa      4.7           NA
 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa      4.6           NA
 5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa      5             NA
 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa      5.4           NA
 7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa      4.6           NA
 8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa      5             NA
 9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa      4.4           NA
10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa      4.9           NA
```

`NA`'s are produced as a side effect.  This can be corrected with `ungroup()`:

```
iris %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(Max.Len = max(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length)) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    mutate(Lead.Max.Len = lead(Max.Len))
```

This will produce the desired output:

```
   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species Max.Len lead.max.len
          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>     <dbl>        <dbl>
 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa      5.1          4.9
 2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa      4.9          4.7
 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa      4.7          4.6
 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa      4.6          5  
 5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa      5            5.4
 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa      5.4          4.6
 7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa      4.6          5  
 8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa      5            4.4
 9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa      4.4          4.9
10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa      4.9          5.4
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
iris$Max.Len <- pmax(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Petal.Length)
```

Comment: Yes thx, that's a very specific answer. But my example and question are trying to tease out if there is a general `dplyr` solution for any scalar function.

Comment: In general, functions should be vectorized -- if it is a wacky function, you might write `wacky.function <- function(col.1, col.2){...}`, and then `iris.wacky <- wacky.function(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Petal.Length)`.

Comment: Often they should I guess, but I think when you are using something like `dplyr` or `plyr` or say `data.table` you should try to use their idioms so that your code doesn't become a difficult to share mix of styles. Hence the question.

Comment: The first line of the `plyr` documentation is "plyr is a set of tools that solves a common set of problems: you need to break a big problem down into manageable pieces, operate on each pieces and then put all the pieces back together."  This seems like a very different problem for which elementary column operations are the best tool.  This also might explain why there's no "natural" `plyr`/`dplyr` command for doing this.

Comment: Uh OK.. but plyr does have a natural way to do this `adply` (see above).

Comment: To butcher a famous quote: "*If all you have is a plyr you will end up using it for a hammer and a screwdriver too*"

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness I am going to change the code of this [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2142208/derek-sonderegger) from the forgotten [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48998542/9550633) (and maybe the best answer) of the question: Sum across multiple columns. And apply it to your problem:

```
iris %>%
  mutate(max = select(.,c('Sepal.Length','Petal.Length')) %>% 
  apply(1, max, na.rm=TRUE))
```

The Result is expected. Accepted answer said that rowwise is increasingly not recommended, and apply is base R. Uou don't need to import an extra package like purrr.

You can use apply() function with max, min, sum, median, mean. So it's very handy and simple.