# add column with row wise mean over selected columns using dplyr

Tags: regex, r, dplyr

I have a data frame which contains several variables which got measured at different time points (e.g., `test1_tp1`, `test1_tp2`, `test1_tp3`, `test2_tp1`, `test2_tp2`,...).

I am now trying to use `dplyr` to add a new column to a data frame that calculates the row wise mean over a selection of these columns (e.g., mean over all time points for `test1`).

1. I struggle even with the syntax for calculating the mean over explicitly named columns. What I tried without success was:

`data %>% ... %>% mutate(test1_mean = mean(test1_tp1, test1_tp2, test1_tp3, na.rm = TRUE)`

2. I would further like to use regex/wildcards to select the column names, so something like

`data %>% ... %>% mutate(test1_mean = mean(matches("test1_.*"), na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: Use `rowwise()` as described in the answer to [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21818181/applying-a-function-to-every-row-of-a-table-using-dplyr).

Comment: Thank you all for your great answers! All of them are very useful... As I don't have enough reputation, I could not upvote your answers, but could only select one as the solution, sorry!

Comment: I would strongly recommend learning about [tidy data](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.html). If your data is a in tidy format, you'll find this sort of operation __much__ easier to do

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `starts_with` inside `select` to find all columns starting with a certain string.

```
data %>%
  mutate(test1 = select(., starts_with("test1_")) %>%
           rowMeans(na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: Can you show how to rewrite this using `rowwise` and `mean` instead of `rowMeans`?

Comment: I tried it but return 'Error in rowMeans(., na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric'. Maybe using `data %>% mutate(., test_mean=rowMean(select(.,starts_with('test1_'))`  is easy to understand.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you could do it in dplyr - I use the iris data as an example:

```
iris %>% mutate(sum.Sepal = rowSums(.[grep("^Sepal", names(.))]))
```

This computes rowwise sums of all columns that start with "Sepal". You can use `rowMeans` instead of `rowSums` the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Not a `dplyr` solution, but you can try:

```
cols_2sum <- grepl('test1',colnames(data))
rowMeans(data[,cols_2sum])
```