# Using 'mutate_' to sum a bunch of columns row-wise

Tags: r, dplyr

[In this blog post](http://www.numbertheory.nl/2015/09/23/using-mutate-from-dplyr-inside-a-function-getting-around-non-standard-evaluation/), Paul Hiemstra shows how to sum up two columns using `dplyr::mutate_`. Copy/paste-ing relevant parts:

```
library(lazyeval)
f = function(col1, col2, new_col_name) {
    mutate_call = lazyeval::interp(~ a + b, a = as.name(col1), b = as.name(col2))
    mtcars %>% mutate_(.dots = setNames(list(mutate_call), new_col_name))
}
```

allows one to then do:

```
head(f('wt', 'mpg', 'hahaaa'))
```

Great!

I followed up with a question (see comments) as to how one could extend this to a 100 columns, since it wasn't quite clear (to me) how one could do it without having to type all the names using the above method. Paul was kind enough to indulge me and provided this answer (thanks!):

```
# data
df = data.frame(matrix(1:100, 10, 10))
names(df) = LETTERS[1:10]

# answer
sum_all_rows = function(list_of_cols) {
  summarise_calls = sapply(list_of_cols, function(col) {
    lazyeval::interp(~col_name, col_name = as.name(col))
  })
  df %>% select_(.dots = summarise_calls) %>% mutate(ans1 = rowSums(.))
}
sum_all_rows(LETTERS[sample(1:10, 5)])
```

I'd like to improve this answer on these points:

1. The other columns are gone. I'd like to keep them.
2. It uses `rowSums()` which has to coerce the *data.frame* to a *matrix* which I'd like to avoid.

   Also I'm not sure if the use of `.` within *non-`do()`* verbs is encouraged? Because `.` within `mutate()` doesn't seem to adapt to just those rows when used with `group_by()`.
3. And most importantly, how can I do the same using `mutate_()` instead of `mutate()`?

I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28159143/add-column-with-row-wise-mean-over-selected-columns-using-dplyr), which addresses point 1, but unfortunately, both `dplyr` answers use `rowSums()` along with `mutate()`.

---

PS: I just read [Hadley's comment under that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28159143/add-column-with-row-wise-mean-over-selected-columns-using-dplyr#comment44694397_28159143). IIUC, 'reshape to long form + group by + sum + reshape to wide form' is the recommend `dplyr` way for these type of operations?

Comment: No need for `library(lazyeval)` when you explicitly qualify its usage anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a different approach:

```
library(dplyr); library(lazyeval)
f <- function(df, list_of_cols, new_col) {
  df %>% 
    mutate_(.dots = ~Reduce(`+`, .[list_of_cols])) %>% 
    setNames(c(names(df), new_col))
}

head(f(mtcars, c("mpg", "cyl"), "x"))
#   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb    x
#1 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 27.0
#2 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 27.0
#3 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 26.8
#4 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 27.4
#5 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 26.7
#6 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1 24.1
```

---

Regarding your points:

- Other columns are kept
- It doesn't use `rowSums`
- You are specifically asking for a row-wise operation here so I'm not sure (yet) how a `group_by` could do any harm when using `.` inside `mutate`/`mutate_`
- It makes use of `mutate_`

Comment: Great! On `.` with `group_by()`, I just find it odd. As an example case, compute the row sum and divide them by max sum within group.. I guess you'd first compute the row sum and then group by and get the ratio? If so, I find it odd (of not being able to do it in one step using mutate, but using `do()`). But perhaps that's by design, no worries. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @docendo discimus. Great answer. Do you know if in the recent releases of dplyr there is some function that adds a column as the sum of  columns matching some regular expression?