# How does one stop using rowwise in dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

So, if one wishes to apply an operation row by row in dplyr, one can use the `rowwise` function, for example: [Applying a function to every row of a table using dplyr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21818181/applying-a-function-to-every-row-of-a-table-using-dplyr/24728107#24728107)

Is there a `unrowwise` function which you can use to stop doing operations row by row? Currently, it seems adding a `group_by` after the `rowwise` removes row operations, e.g.

```
data.frame(a=1:4) %>% rowwise() %>% group_by(a)
# ...
# Warning message:
# Grouping rowwise data frame strips rowwise nature
```

Does this mean one should use `group_by(1)` if you wish to explicitly remove `rowwise`?

Comment: Does `ungroup()` work?

Comment: I rolled-back the title edit as it is not clear to me that `rowwise` creates a `grouped_df`.  Also, see this related issue. https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/pull/553

Answer (score 96, accepted):

As found in the comments and the other answer, the correct way of doing this is to use `ungroup()`.

The operation `rowwise(df)` sets one of the classes of `df` to be `rowwise_df`. We can see the methods on this class by examining the code [here](http://ungroup.rowwise_df%20%3C-%20function(x)%20%7B%20%20%20class(x)%20%3C-%20c(), which gives the following `ungroup` method:

```
#' @export
ungroup.rowwise_df <- function(x) {
  class(x) <- c( "tbl_df", "data.frame")
  x
}
```

So we see that `ungroup` is not strictly removing a grouped structure, instead it just removes the `rowwise_df` class added from the `rowwise` function.

Comment: Link no longer works :-( Too bad the code wasn't copied here instead.

Comment: but, it is, as in, the code block is the relevant code that deals with ungroup

Answer (score 17):

Just use `ungroup()`

The following produces a warning:

```
data.frame(a=1:4) %>% rowwise() %>% 
  group_by(a)
#Warning message:
#Grouping rowwise data frame strips rowwise nature
```

This does not produce the warning:

```
data.frame(a=1:4) %>% rowwise() %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  group_by(a)
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `as.data.frame()`, like below

```
> data.frame(a=1:4) %>% rowwise() %>% group_by(a)
# A tibble: 4 x 1
# Groups:   a [4]
      a
* <int>
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     4
Warning message:
Grouping rowwise data frame strips rowwise nature 

> data.frame(a=1:4) %>% rowwise() %>% as.data.frame() %>% group_by(a)
# A tibble: 4 x 1
# Groups:   a [4]
      a
* <int>
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     4
```