# When does dplyr's ungroup() function drop the 'vars' attribute?

Tags: r, dplyr

I intuitively expected using the `ungroup()` function would drop the 'vars' attribute.  Sometimes it does and sometimes it doesn't.  What is the rule?  I'm trying to understand the internals of grouping/ungrouping.

Consider the two examples below (using dplyr 0.7.4 on R 3.4.4).  In the first one the 'vars' attribute is retained.  In the second it is dropped.

```
#Example 1
models <- mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% do(mod = lm(mpg ~ disp, data = .)) 
   %>% ungroup() 
attributes(models)
```

> $row.names   [1] 1 2 3
>
> $vars   [1] "cyl"
>
> $drop   [1] TRUE
>
> $names   [1] "cyl" "mod"
>
> $class   [1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"

```
#Example 2
attributes(mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% count() %>% ungroup())
```

> $class   [1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
>
> $names   [1] "cyl" "n"
>
> $row.names   [1] 1 2 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference comes from the fact that `group_by %>% do` returns a `rowwise_df` while `group_by %>% count` returns a `grouped_df`, and for `rowwise_df`, `ungroup` only removes the `rowwise_df` class attribute and leaves other rowwise related attributes untouched, also see this [How does one stop using rowwise in dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29762393/how-does-one-stop-using-rowwise-in-dplyr):

```
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% do(mod = lm(mpg ~ disp, data = .)) %>% class()
# [1] "rowwise_df" "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"

mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% count() %>% class()
# [1] "grouped_df" "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```