# How to do rowwise summation over selected columns using column index with dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

In `dplyr`, how do you perform rowwise summation over selected columns (using column index)?

This doesn't work

```
> iris  %>% mutate(sum=sum(.[1:4])) %>% head
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species    sum
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa 2078.7
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa 2078.7
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa 2078.7
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa 2078.7
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa 2078.7
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa 2078.7
```

I can do the following, but it's not beautiful

```
> iris %>% mutate(index=1:n()) %>%  
                gather("param", "value", 1:4)  %>% 
                group_by(index) %>% 
                mutate(sum=sum(value)) %>% 
                spread(param, value) %>% select(-index)
Source: local data frame [150 x 6]

   Species  sum Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
1   setosa 10.2          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2
2   setosa  9.5          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2
3   setosa  9.4          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2
4   setosa  9.4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2
5   setosa 10.2          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2
6   setosa 11.4          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4
7   setosa  9.7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3
8   setosa 10.1          5.0         3.4          1.5         0.2
9   setosa  8.9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2
10  setosa  9.6          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1
..     ...  ...          ...         ...          ...         ...
```

Is there more syntactically nicer way to achieve this?

EDIT: It's different from other questions, because I want to do rowwise operation on the columns selected by *using column indices*"

Comment: Try `iris  %>% mutate(sum=Reduce("+",.[1:4]))`. Alternatively, the base `rowSums` function does what you are asking for.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Applying a function to every row of a table using dplyr?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21818181/applying-a-function-to-every-row-of-a-table-using-dplyr)

Comment: `dplyr` offers the `rowwise` function that maybe might be helpful.

Comment: As showed in the link, an option would be `rowwise` with `do` i.e. `iris %>% rowwise() %>% do(data.frame(., sum=sum(unlist(.[1:4]))))`

Comment: @nicola I like your answer the best. Can you make that into an answer so that I can pick it as a final answer?

Comment: @Alby Glad you appreciated it. I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As already said in the comment, you can accomplish your task with:

```
iris %>% mutate(sum=Reduce("+",.[1:4]))
```

In this case also the base `rowSums` works:

```
iris$sum<-rowSums(iris[,1:4])
```

Comment: I realize the OP wanted to use the column index, but is there a way to use the column names?  I'm thinking of something like the select function select(df, V4:V13).  Not sure how to put this in here.

Answer (score 1):

You can (ab)use base R's `subset`, which allows selection of columns by number:

```
iris %>% subset(select=1:4) %>% mutate(sum=rowSums(.))
```

Comment: The `dplyr` `select` function seems to work fine: `iris %>% select(1:4) %>% mutate(sum=rowSums(.))`..?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is correct etiquette but I prefer to recycle this thread instead of starting a new one given, I am pretty sure, I am doing just a rookie mistake.

Why is this working alright:

```
test$sum <- Reduce("+", test[,3:ncol(test)])
```

while this (to me identical) doesn't?

```
test %>%
  mutate(sum = Reduce("+",.[3:ncol(.)]))
```

The error given is

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `sum` must be length 1 (the group size), not 915
```

I am banging my head on the desk since 30' or so!

I wish I could give you the underlying dataset but I really can't.

Column 1:2 are text fields while 3:ncol(.) are TRUE/FALSE (logical) ones. ncol(.) = 33.

Answer (score 0):

I think the ability to do row-wise operations is a weak point of the tidyverse syntax, but `purrr:pmap_*` is useful to run this, although it is not that obvious:

```
iris %>% 
  mutate(total = pmap_dbl(select(., -Species), sum))

    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width    Species  total
1            5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2     setosa  10.2
2            4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2     setosa   9.5
3            4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2     setosa   9.4
4            4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2     setosa   9.4
5            5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2     setosa  10.2
```

Alternatively, you can use `select_if(., is.numeric)` instead of `select(., -Species)` to be more generalized (but it will not work if there are some numeric variables you don't want included in the calculation).