# Rowwise summation for Tibble datatype

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a Tibble, and I have noticed that a combination of `dplyr::rowwise()` and `sum()` doesn't work. I know there are many threads on this topic, and I have got 2 to 3 solutions, but I am not quite why the combination of `rowwise()` and `sum()` doesn't work.

So, my **question** is : why doesn't a combination of `rowwise()` and `sum()` work AND what can we do to make it work? I am a beginner so I believe that I am doing something wrong in the below code.

**Data:**

```
dput(data)
structure(list(Fiscal.Year = c(2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L, 2016L), col1 = c(0, 26613797.764311, 
0, 12717073.587292, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), col2 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 8969417.89721166, 
0, 11483606.8417117, 0, 0, 0), col3 = c(0, 0, 33251606.347943, 
0, 25082683.4492186, 0, 17337191.3014127, 0, 0, 0), col4 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), col5 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 9796823.229998), col6 = c(35822181.695755, 17475066.870565, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 4040695.327278, 0, 13117249.623068, 0), col7 = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 18347258.910001, 0, 0, 7002205.087399, 0), No.Trans = c(2987L, 
1292L, 1002L, 796L, 691L, 677L, 400L, 388L, 381L, 366L)), .Names = c("Fiscal.Year", 
"col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5", "col6", "col7", "No.Trans"
), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

**This code doesn't work:**

```
data %>%  #No
        dplyr::rowwise() %>%
        dplyr::mutate(sum = sum(.[2:8]))
```

---

Just for reference, I have tried the following set of code, and they work. I am specifically looking for a solution that uses `rowwise()` and `sum()`.

**Option 1:** 
Discussed at: [Summarise over all columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28095526/summarise-over-all-columns?noredirect=1&lq=1)

```
  data %>%
    dplyr::rowwise() %>%
    do(data.frame(., res = sum(unlist(.)[2:8])))
```

**Option 2:**

```
  rowSums(data[,2:8])
```

**Option 3:**
Discussed at:[How to do rowwise summation over selected columns using column index with dplyr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31193101/how-to-do-rowwise-summation-over-selected-columns-using-column-index-with-dplyr)

```
  data %>% mutate(sum=Reduce("+",.[2:8]))
```

**Option 4:**

```
data %>%
        select(2:8)%>%
        dplyr::mutate(sum=rowSums(.))
```

Comment: Why do you need to go through this route, it is not efficient compared to some of the methods you mentioned in the post

Comment: @akrun - Thanks for your question. "By efficient", are you referring to the one from base R? As a beginner, I believe that I lack knowledge about `dplyr`. Hence, I want to learn how to fix errors. This would just help me.

Comment: The two methods `rowSums` and `Reduce` are very efficient

Comment: Regarding why it doesn't work, I am not sure.  The values you are getting is the same as `data[-1] %>% rowwise() %>%  sum` ie. sum of entire values, it could be a bug or design feature

Answer (score 2):

Those columns look suspiciously like observations....
If so, tidying that dataframe up would make the data wrangling significantly easier.

Does this get you the answers you are seeking?

```
data %>%
    gather(key = col, val = revenue, `col1`:`col7`) %>%
    group_by(Fiscal.Year, No.Trans) %>%
    summarise(res = sum(revenue))

Source: local data frame [10 x 3]
Groups: Fiscal.Year [?]

   Fiscal.Year No.Trans      res
         <int>    <int>    <dbl>
1         2016      366  9796823
2         2016      381 20119455
3         2016      388        0
4         2016      400 32861493
5         2016      677 18347259
6         2016      691 34052101
7         2016      796 12717074
8         2016     1002 33251606
9         2016     1292 44088865
10        2016     2987 35822182
```

For a really smooth introduction to thinking tidily please try [here](https://vimeo.com/33727555). The functions he discusses in the presentation have been updated, but Hadley does a great job teaching the subject: through pedagogical chaining, as it were.

The updated functions can be found in his *ggplot2* book [here](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2-book/blob/master/tidy-data.rmd).