# Row-wise summation for grouped_df data type

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I am a beginner and not too familiar with advanced features of R. I am unable to understand why `reduce()` doesn't work for `grouped_df`. I am building upon my discussion at [Rowwise summation for Tibble datatype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41518323/rowwise-summation-for-tibble-datatype) where I posted `reduce()` as one of the solutions when the class of datatype is:

```
"tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

Here's the sample data:

```
  df <- data.frame(client = rep(c("Client A","Client B", "Client C"),3), 
                       year = rep(c(2014,2013,2012), each=3), 
                       rev1 = rep(c(10,20,30),3),
                       rev2 = rep(c(10,20,30),3))
```

where, `class (df)` is `"tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"`

I'd now convert `df` to of class `grouped_df` by :

```
df1 <- df %>% 
        group_by(client, year,rev1) %>%
        summarise(rev3 = sum(rev1,rev2)) %>%
        select(client, year, rev3, rev1)
```

where, `class (df1)` is `"grouped_df" "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"`, which is as expected.

Now, when I use `reduce()` to do row-wise summation on `df1`, it throws an error.

```
df1%>% dplyr::mutate(sum=Reduce("+",.[3:4]))
Error: incompatible size (9), expecting 1 (the group size) or 1
```

However, when I convert `df1` to data frame, it works well.

```
df1%>% dplyr::as_data_frame() %>%  dplyr::mutate(sum=Reduce("+",.[3:4]))
```

The `head()` of above output is:

```
# A tibble: 6 × 5
    client  year  rev3  rev1   sum
    <fctr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 Client A  2012    20    10    30
2 Client A  2013    20    10    30
3 Client A  2014    20    10    30
4 Client B  2012    40    20    60
5 Client B  2013    40    20    60
6 Client B  2014    40    20    60
...
```

Can someone please explain why `reduce()` function doesn't work for grouped data, but works for non-grouped data? Maybe, I am missing something here.

Comment: @Sotos - yes, that's a typo. I am going to correct this. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You're not using the `replace()` function in any of your code blocks above. You're using the `Reduce()` function.

As an aside, `df()` is a density distribution function in the `stats` package - it's bad practice to assign objects to functions.

Comment: This is not an answer. Please avoid posting comments as answers. Once you get enough reputation you will be able to comment anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

`Reduce()` and `replace()` work on vectors.

The df1 grouped dataframe becomes much more than a collection of vectors. Below is what it looks like if you flip open the objects (found in the environment pane.)
[image: df and df1 under the hood]

If we add an `ungroup()` we can get a collection of vectors back.

```
df2 <- df %>% 
    group_by(client, year,rev1) %>%
    summarise(rev3 = sum(rev1,rev2)) %>%
    select(client, year, rev3, rev1) %>% 
    ungroup %>% 
    mutate(sum=Reduce("+",.[3:4]))
```

In any case, could maybe this *dplyr* code work instead?

```
mutate(df, rev3 = rev1 + rev2, sum = 2*rev1 + rev2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I believe using `as_data_frame()` and `ungroup()` will have the same effect. Do you mind explaining what would happen if we `ungroup()` the data? Why is it that `reduce()` doesn't work on grouped data? I'm still unclear about the "why".

Comment: watch your enviroment as you do it to you dataframe. Nothing much happens expect that if flips back to a simple dataframe (collection of vectors again.) in that you drop all the attributes that the `grouped_df()` builds. See here:https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/master/R/grouped-df.r  Reduce wants vectors and when you feed it an `attr()` it gets a mouth full of fur and coughs it back at you: figuratively. :-D [I am curious to hear what others have to offer, too.]

Comment: btw: `class(attr)` = "function" but now I suspect it has more to do with the same type of issue as `fill` had. https://github.com/tidyverse/tidyr/commit/849aab524eb4e2e4ac8a32ddc4930dc78917c824 per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34517370/group-by-into-fill-not-working-as-expected

Comment: To be honest, I have never seen anyone yet be able to explain why `group_by` causes the trip ups it does. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/21656344/5088194 (and note the ten upvotes on the first comment :-D)  I just know that when you start getting warnings after a `group_by` complaining about inappropriate lengths it means you need to either `ungroup` your chain or in earlier editions I recall throwing in a `rowwise()` farther up the chain. I've never had time to disassemble the apparatus before, but it does appear to me that functions don't like to be fed functions.

Comment: @ hightower - It looks similar to this behavior: [lag() & lead() Issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28235074/dplyr-lead-and-lag-wrong-when-used-with-group-by) and Romain Francois sorted it out here: [bug fix #925](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/commit/98e2efac07d87722c0acf1368f223423dc7edcd5). Maybe you could raise the issue to Hadley and Romain as a bug? I think that will get you the most complete answer.