# Count number of values in row using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

This question should have a simple, elegant solution but I can't figure it out, so here it goes:

Let's say I have the following dataset and I want to count the number of 2s present in each row using dplyr.

```
set.seed(1)
ID <- LETTERS[1:5]
X1 <- sample(1:5, 5,T)
X2 <- sample(1:5, 5,T)
X3 <- sample(1:5, 5,T)

df <- data.frame(ID,X1,X2,X3)
library(dplyr)
```

Now, the following works:

```
df %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(numtwos = sum(c(X1,X2,X3) == 2))
```

But how do I avoid typing out all of the column names?

I know this is probably easier to do without `dplyr`, but more generally I want to know how I can use `dplyr`'s `mutate` with multiple columns without typing out all the column names.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try `rowSums`:

```
> set.seed(1)
> ID <- LETTERS[1:5]
> X1 <- sample(1:5, 5,T)
> X2 <- sample(1:5, 5,T)
> X3 <- sample(1:5, 5,T)
> df <- data.frame(ID,X1,X2,X3)
> df
  ID X1 X2 X3
1  A  2  5  2
2  B  2  5  1
3  C  3  4  4
4  D  5  4  2
5  E  2  1  4
> rowSums(df == 2)
[1] 2 1 0 1 1
```

Alternatively, with `dplyr`:

```
> df %>% mutate(numtwos = rowSums(. == 2))
  ID X1 X2 X3 numtwos
1  A  2  5  2       2
2  B  2  5  1       1
3  C  3  4  4       0
4  D  5  4  2       1
5  E  2  1  4       1
```

Comment: I mentioned that I specifically want to know how to do this with dplyr, even if it isn't the best solution.

Comment: @C_Z_ see my most recent edit, I think it is the shortest `dplyr` solution

Comment: How exactly does `.` work? Is it like `.SD` in `data.table`?

Comment: I think `.` is just a way to reference the `df` you are mutating

Answer (score 6):

Here's another alternative using `purrr`:

```
library(purrr)

df %>%
  by_row(function(x) {
    sum(x[-1] == 2) },
    .to = "numtwos",
    .collate = "cols"
  )
```

Which gives:

```
#Source: local data frame [5 x 5]
#
#      ID    X1    X2    X3 numtwos
#  <fctr> <int> <int> <int>   <int>
#1      A     2     5     2       2
#2      B     2     5     1       1
#3      C     3     4     4       0
#4      D     5     4     2       1
#5      E     2     1     4       1
```

---

As per mentioned in the [NEWS](https://github.com/hadley/purrr/blob/master/NEWS.md), row based functionals are still maturing in `dplyr`:

> We are still figuring out what belongs in `dplyr` and what belongs in
>   `purrr`. Expect much experimentation and many changes with these
>   functions.

---

**Benchmark**

We can see how `rowwise()` and `do()` compare to `purrr::by_row()` for this type of problem and how they "perform" against `rowSums()` and the tidy data way:

```
largedf <-  df[rep(seq_len(nrow(df)), 10e3), ]

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  steven = largedf %>% 
    by_row(function(x) { 
      sum(x[-1] == 2) }, 
      .to = "numtwos", 
      .collate = "cols"),
  psidom = largedf %>% 
    rowwise %>% 
    do(data_frame(numtwos = sum(.[-1] == 2))) %>% 
    cbind(largedf, .),
  gopala = largedf %>% 
    gather(key, value, -ID) %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% 
    summarise(numtwos = sum(value == 2)) %>% 
    inner_join(largedf, .),
  evan   = largedf %>% 
    mutate(numtwos = rowSums(. == 2)),
  times  = 10L,
  unit   = "relative"
)
```

Results:

```
#Unit: relative
#   expr         min          lq        mean      median         uq         max neval cld
# steven 1225.190659 1261.466936 1267.737126 1227.762573 1276.07977 1339.841636    10  b 
# psidom 3677.603240 3759.402212 3726.891458 3678.717170 3728.78828 3777.425492    10   c
# gopala    2.715005    2.684599    2.638425    2.612631    2.59827    2.572972    10 a  
#   evan    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.000000    1.00000    1.000000    10 a
```

Comment: That looks purrrfect

Comment: Purrrfect indeed ;) Although from recent experiments `by_row()` is painfuly slow for large dataset.

Comment: @StevenBeaupré cool comparison! Thanks for putting that together!

Answer (score 6):

Just wanted to add to the answer of @evan.oman in case you only want to sum rows for specific columns, not all of them. You can use the regular `select` and/or `select_helpers` functions. In this example, we don't want to include `X1` in `rowSums`:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(numtwos = rowSums(select(., -X1) == 2))

  ID X1 X2 X3 numtwos
1  A  2  5  2       1
2  B  2  5  1       0
3  C  3  4  4       0
4  D  5  4  2       1
5  E  2  1  4       0
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to use a combination of `dplyr` and `tidyr` to convert data into long format, and do the computation:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
  gather(key, value, -ID) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise(numtwos = sum(value == 2)) %>%
  inner_join(df, .)
```

Output is as follows:

```
  ID X1 X2 X3 numtwos
1  A  2  5  2       2
2  B  2  5  1       1
3  C  3  4  4       0
4  D  5  4  2       1
5  E  2  1  4       1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `do`, which doesn't add the column to your original data frame and you need to add the column to your original data frame.

```
df %>%
    rowwise %>%
    do(numtwos = sum(.[-1] == 2)) %>% 
    data.frame
  numtwos
1       2
2       1
3       0
4       1
5       1
```

Add a `cbind` to bind the new column to the original data frame:

```
df %>%
     rowwise %>%
     do(numtwos = sum(.[-1] == 2)) %>% 
     data.frame %>% cbind(df, .)

  ID X1 X2 X3 numtwos
1  A  2  5  2       2
2  B  2  5  1       1
3  C  3  4  4       0
4  D  5  4  2       1
5  E  2  1  4       1
```

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping `dplyr` had a cleaner way to do this. Oh well!

Comment: Rowwise operation is always kind of painful both in `dplyr` and `data.table` since the data is column-wise stored from my understanding.

Comment: @Arun, Thanks for clarifying. That's what I am guessing too.

Answer (score 0):

**For `dplyr > 1.0.0`**, below is a quick solution using `across()` to specific column ranges to operate on:

```
df %>% 
   mutate(numtwos = rowSums(across(X1:X3, ~ .x == 2)))

     ID X1 X2 X3 numtwos
  1  A  2  5  2       2
  2  B  2  5  1       1
  3  C  3  4  4       0
  4  D  5  4  2       1
  5  E  2  1  4       1
```