# In R, How do I filter a data frame to only include rows with >=2 non-NA values?

Tags: r, filter

Suppose I have a dataframe

```
      Grp1 Grp2 Grp3
Trt1    NA    1   NA
Trt2     2    3   NA
Trt3     4   NA    5
```

I'd like to filter this down to only include rows where the number of non-NA values is greater than some total (in this case 2). So for this example I would like a result:

```
      Grp1 Grp2 Grp3
Trt2     2    3   NA
Trt3     4   NA    5
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35443115/add-a-column-with-count-of-nas-and-mean-in-r-with-dplyr

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `rowSums()` and `is.na()` to filter the dataframe. This will coerce the values you are using to filter into a matrix (so it may have issues with *very* large dataframes), but it should do the trick.

```
df1[rowSums(!is.na(df1)) >= 2, ]
     Grp1 Grp2 Grp3
Trt2    2    3   NA
Trt3    4   NA    5
```

**Data**:

```
df1 <- read.table(header = T, text = "      Grp1 Grp2 Grp3
Trt1    NA    1   NA
Trt2     2    3   NA
Trt3     4   NA    5")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it this way :

```
count_na <- apply(data, 1, function(x) sum(is.na(x)))
data[count_na < 2,]
```

sample data:

```
  col1 col2 col3
1    1    1   NA
2   NA   NA    2
3   NA    3    3
```

new output:

```
  col1 col2 col3
1    1    1   NA
3   NA    3    3
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
data[apply(data,1,function(x) sum(!is.na(x)) >= 2),]
```