# Simple mutate with dplyr gives "wrong result size" error

Tags: r, dplyr

My data table `df` has a `subject` column (e.g. "SubjectA", "SubjectB", ...). Each subject answers many questions, and the table is in long format, so there are many rows for each subject. The subject column is a factor. I want to create a new column - call it `subject.id` - that is simply a numeric version of `subject`. So for all rows with "SubjectA", it would be 1; for all rows with "SubjectB", it would be 2; etc.

I know that an easy way to do this with `dplyr` would be to call `df %>% mutate(subject.id = as.numeric(subject))`. But I was trying to do it this way:

```
subj.list <- unique(as.character(df$subject))
df %>% mutate(subject.id = which(as.character(subject) == subj.list))
```

And I get this error:

```
Error: wrong result size (12), expected 72 or 1
```

**Why does this happen?** I'm not interested in other ways to solve this particular problem. Rather, I worry that my inability to understand this error reflects a deep misunderstanding of `dplyr` or `mutate`. My understanding is that this call should be conceptually equivalent to:

```
df$subject.id <- NULL
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
   df$subject.id[i] <- which(as.character(df$subject[i]) == subj.list))
}
```

But the latter works and the former doesn't. Why?

**Reproducible example:**

```
df <- InsectSprays %>% rename(subject = spray)
subj.list <- unique(as.character(df$subject))

# this works
df$subject.id <- NULL
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
   df$subject.id[i] <- which(as.character(df$subject[i]) == subj.list)
}

# but this doesn't
df %>% mutate(subject.id = which(as.character(subject) == subj.list))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that operators and functions are applied in a vectorized way by mutate. Thus, `which` is applied to the vector produced by `as.character(df$subject) == subj.list`, not to each row (as in your loop).

Using `rowwise` as described here would solve the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24728107/3772587

So, this will work:

```
df %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(subject.id = which(as.character(subject) == subj.list))
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your `df$subject` is a factor, you could simply do:

```
df %>% mutate(subj.id=as.numeric(subject))
```

Or use a left join approach:

```
subj.df <- df$subject %>% 
    unique() %>% 
    as_tibble() %>% 
    rownames_to_column(var = 'subj.id')

df %>% left_join(subj.df,by = c("subject"="value"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I know there are other ways to solve the particular problem, but my question is why the one I proposed doesn't work. I'm worried that I have some deep misunderstanding of `mutate` or `dplyr`.

Comment: @AdamMorris ah, hmm. I can't answer that offhand! Hope someone can help out!