# dplyr - apply a custom function using rowwise()

Tags: r, dplyr, rowwise

I have a data frame and want to count the number of zeros in each row using dplyr's rowwise. What am I doing wrong?

```
dt2 = data.frame(A = c(8, 6), B = c(0, 0), C = c(0, 5))
dt2
zerocount <- function(x) {sum(x == 0)}
library(dplyr)
dt2 %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(nr_of_0s = zerocount(A, B, C))
```

The code above works if I replace zerocount(A, B, C) in the line above with, for example, max(A, B, C). What is wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Applying a function to every row of a table using dplyr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21818181/applying-a-function-to-every-row-of-a-table-using-dplyr)

Comment: I've read that link but didn't see a direct application to my question.

Comment: I don't think your problem is with rowwise. The way your function is written, it's expecting a single object. Try adding a c(): `dt2 %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(nr_of_0s = zerocount(c(A, B, C)))`

Comment: unfortunate that you specified `rowwise`. This is pretty effective too 
`dt2 %>% mutate(zero.count = rowSums(.==0) )`

Comment: @benc - thank you very much for your comment. Would you please provide it as a response so that I could upvote you?

Comment: @Nettle - Thank you very much, indeed, it works well too!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think your problem is with rowwise. The way your function is written, it's expecting a single object. Try adding a c():

```
dt2 %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(nr_of_0s = zerocount(c(A, B, C)))
```

Note that, if you aren't committed to using your own function, you can skip rowwise entirely, as Nettle also notes. `rowSums` already treats data frames in a rowwise fashion, which is why this works:

```
dt2 %>% mutate(nr_of_0s = rowSums(. == 0))
```

Answer (score 2):

A logical test for the presence of zeros would look like:

```
 dt2==0
         A    B     C
[1,] FALSE TRUE  TRUE
[2,] FALSE TRUE FALSE
```

Sum the number of Trues by row

```
rowSums(dt2==0)
[1] 2 1
```

With this in mind, here's a tidyverse solution:

```
dt2 %>% 
  mutate(zero.count = rowSums(.==0) ) #<The dot is shorthand for dt2 

  A B C zero.count
1 8 0 0          2
2 6 0 5          1
```

Comment: Please provide some more explanation about your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Another method without using `rowwise()`:

```
mutate(dt2, zero_count = pmap_int(dt2, function(...) sum(c(...) == 0)))

>   A B C zero_count
> 1 8 0 0          2
> 2 6 0 5          1
```

`pmap()` is a `purrr` function that takes takes elements from a list (which in this case is the data frame) and applies a function. In this case, I'm just applying your function on the fly. By default, `pmap()` returns a list, but using the `_int` suffix makes it return an integer vector.