# What is a good alternative to using rowwise() for row-wise operations on a column in a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, rowwise

I am trying to perform a string operation on one of the columns in my data frame `Test_df`. This dataframe has close to 5mil records. The objective is to count the occurrences of a character in a string (after replacing the nulls) and i am using the `str_locate` to count.

Since this is a row-wise mutation, i tried using the `rowwise()` function with `dplyr`.

```
Test_df <- Test_df%>%
        rowwise() %>%
          mutate(col1 = replace_na(str_locate(as.character(my_string),"2")[1],999))
```

This line took more than 5 hours to execute which was extremely sub-optimal.

I then tried using the `purrr:pmap` function to speed up the process a little as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21818181/applying-a-function-to-every-row-of-a-table-using-dplyr) Stack Overflow Thread but this did not help speed up the process.

```
Test_DF <- Test_DF%>%mutate(col1 = purrr::pmap_dbl(list(Test_DF$my_string), function(a) replace_na(str_locate(a,"2")[1],999)))
```

Is there a way to do `replace_na` and `str_locate` so that the execution is faster? I need to do this on a monthly basis.

Comment: If you want to count the number of characters, you can simply use `nchar()` which is already vectorized to you don't need `rowwise()`.

Comment: Use `str_count` to count. You shouldn't need to use `rowwise` with it. If you need more help, please share a little bit of sample data and the desired result. Though, without seeing your input, I'm not sure why you need to use `rowwise` even with `str_locate`...

Comment: @Shakir data table vs dplyr is irrelevant here. There aren't joins or grouped operations. OP is operating on each element of a vector---the only performance question that matters is whether or not that operation can be vectorized.

Comment: Yes... I was over complicating things. Thank you everyone for your wise comments.

:)