# How to pass a record of data.frame to a function as parameter?

Tags: r

Anyway, I simplfy my question. We have a dataframe like this:

```
dt <- data.frame(x=c(1,2,3), y=c("a", "b", "c"))
f <- function(x, y){
  #f is a function that only take vector whose length is one.
}
```

So I need to use f function like the following:

```
  f(1, "a")
  f(2, "b")
  f(3, "c")
```

I know I can use for-loop as the following:

```
  for (i in 1:3) {
    f(dt$x[i], dt$y[i])
  }
```

But it seems stupid and ugly.
Is there any better way to do such work?

Comment: What are you expecting as a result of the function `f` ?

Comment: This previous question might be worth a read: [how to call apply-like function on each row of dataframe with multiple arguments from each row of the df](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15059076/r-how-to-call-apply-like-function-on-each-row-of-dataframe-with-multiple-argum/15059295)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one option would be to `vectorize` the function `f` which works nicely in some cases (i.e. vector return values), as in:

```
# returs a vector of length 1
f = function(x,y)paste(x[1],y[1])
# returs a vector with length == nrow(dt)
Vectorize(f)(dt$x,dt$y)

# returs a vector of length 2
f = function(x,y)rep(x[1],1)
# returns a matrix with 2 rows and nrow(dt) columns
Vectorize(f)(dt$x,dt$y)

f = function(x,y)rep(y[1],x[1])
# returns a list with length == nrow(dt)
Vectorize(f)(dt$x,dt$y)
```

but not in others (i.e. compound return values [lists]), as in:

```
# returns a list
f = function(x,y)list(x[1],y[1])
# returns a matrix but the second row is not useful
Vectorize(f)(dt$x,dt$y)
```

Comment: For a data frame with many columns, it would be convenient to use `do.call(Vectorize(f),dt)`