# Applying custom functions to each row in a dataframe in r

Tags: r

I am trying to using each row in a data frame as inputs to a function to process some data and then write the output to a csv file. As per the following example

```
myfunction <- function(X, Y, Z){

                       data <- read.csv("mydata.csv")
                       subsetedData <- subset(data, x=X & y=Y & z=Z, select=x:z)
                       write.csv(subsetedData, file="mycsvfile.csv")
                       }

apply(myXYZdata, MARGIN = 1, function(x1, x2, x3) myfunction(X, Y, Z))
```

I want to subset based on every row in the dataframe myXYZdata. However this does not appear to work or I am not fully understanding the correct usage of apply.

I know this can be done using a loop but would prefer not to do it that way.

Edit:

The purpose of this is that I have a large data file which I want to subset based on combinations of variables found in my data frame "myXYZdata" and store the results in new data files.

The large data file I want to subset is in the format.

```
date                      x   y  z    count          
1 2015-08-20 00:00:00.000 a   d  h    56
2 2015-08-26 00:00:00.000 b   e  h     4
3 2015-08-18 00:00:00.000 b   f  i     8
4 2015-09-03 00:00:00.000 c   e  l     32
5 2015-08-12 00:00:00.000 a   g  l     3
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [R - how to call apply-like function on each row of dataframe with multiple arguments from each row of the df](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15059076/r-how-to-call-apply-like-function-on-each-row-of-dataframe-with-multiple-argum)

Comment: `apply(myXYZdata, MARGIN = 1, function(x) myfunction(x$X, x$Y, x$Z))` should do.

Comment: Surely this is an [XY problem (What is an XY problem?)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Sounds like you're trying to index into a very large DB file, with logical indexing, using a compound index/multiindex. Or you could use a hash. Can you restate your question with more context? What size are these items?

Comment: Yes you are probably correct this does look like an XY problem, Sorry about that. I have edited my original post to include what I am trying  to do.

Comment: *"I want to subset a large (Gb?) data file based on combinations of variables found in my data and store the results in new data files."* **This really smells like multiindexing into a huge disk-backed DB file to get views. Look into HDFS, R bigmemory vs ff etc.**

Comment: Thanks. No its not in Gb in size. The reason I am doing this is because the number of possibilities of views. If it was large enough I would have use HDFS. Hadoop/HDFS is the solution I probably will use if I take a larger date range. but I have found a solution which works for now. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4):

I believe its easier to pass a row as argument to your function.

```
myfunction <- function(row){

                   data <- read.csv("mydata.csv")
                   subsetedData <- subset(data, x=row[1] & y=row[2] & z=row[3], select=x:z)
                   write.csv(subsetedData, file="mycsvfile.csv")
                   }

apply(myXYZdata[,c("X","Y","Z")], MARGIN = 1, myfunction)
```

Answer (score 2):

What about using `mapply` (multi-variable apply):

```
mapply(myfunction, myXYZdata$X, myXYZdata$Y, myXYZdata$Z, fnms)
```

You will need to create a vector of file names (`fnms`) so that each entry is written to a different file and then change `myfunction` so that it takes an argument for the file name.

Alternatively put `append = TRUE` as an argument to `write.csv` in `myfunction` to get it all written to the same file (but be aware that successive runs of the code will not overwrite the file - you could precede the `write.csv(..., append = TRUE)` with `if(file.exists("mycsvfile.csv")) file.remove("mycsvfile.csv")`).

Comment: Thanks, this has worked in part but is only saving the file for the last row in the data frame.

Comment: The update should help.  That problem will require you to change your function.