# In R, how do I use apply() with data frames?

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply, sapply

apply() allows you to select whether rows or columns with MARGIN=1 or MARGIN=2, respectively.

But apply only works on matrices.

For example, I have three rows of header information and 3 columns of descriptive information.  I need to combine these into row names and row names and column names, respectively.  So I can't easily use read.table() and skip the first 3 rows, and then delete the first 3 columns to get my matrix right away.

This doesn't work on data frames, just matrices

```
rownames(df)<-apply(df[,1:3], MARGIN=1,FUN=function(x){paste(x,sep=".")})
```

Comment: You seem to just want `do.call(paste, c(df[1:3], sep = "."))`.  And you  shouldn't try to use `apply()` on data frames.  It is for matrices, and using it on data frames will yield unintended results almost all the time.

Comment: Richard, this is a good approach, but I think do.call parsers over members of the list, which in this case are the columns.  Can this be modified to do this operating row by row?

Comment: @RichScriven what's the best alternative?

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude the non-numeric columns/rows and deploy apply function onto the numeric rows.

**Consider an example:**
If a data frame has 4 columns out of which the first one belongs to the character class, then use below code:

```
apply(Data.df[,2:4],2,func_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, please note this is not a problem for columns.  lapply will do columns without trouble

```
colnames(df) <- lapply(df[1:3,], function(x) {paste(x,sep=".")})
```

A great answer by rsoren is found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15059076/call-apply-like-function-on-each-row-of-dataframe-with-multiple-arguments-from-e/37599989#37599989)).  Modified for this problem:

```
for (row in 1:nrow(df)) { 
    rownames(df)[row] <- paste(df[row,1:3],sep=".") 
}
```

You can't do rows with lapply.  Here is an alternate, more intuitive approach.  To operate on rows, we make the transpose first; now the rows are columns and lapply can operate on the columns.

```
tdf<-as.data.frame(t(df))
rownames(df) <- lapply(tdf[1:3,], function(x) {paste(x,sep=".")})
```

The only downside to this is that R makes a copy of the table during the transpose, so it doubles memory usage.  However, rsoren's method does not.

Now I can delete the extra rows and columns and make the matrix I want with proper row and column names.

```
myMatrix <- as.matrix(df[-(1:3),-(1:3)])
```

Comment: (deleted answer to deleted comment)

Comment: Careful. Transposing a data frame is generally a bad idea - this will not preserve the class of the original data. Furthermore, you can easily use `lapply()` to index the rows. For example something like this: `lapply(1:3, function(i){ paste(df[i, 1:3], sep = ".") } )`