# Creating one new column in R from the input of multiple existing columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have typical survey style data in R. Multiple columns with binary -- yes/no -- records. I'm looking to create a single, categorical column based on those columns.

We'll call the dataframe schools

```
    PreK  Kindergarten First Second Third Fourth ... 
1    yes      yes       no     no    no    no 
2    no       no        yes    yes   yes   yes
```

I'd like the new column to look like this

```
                                         ...       Grades
1                                                 prek, kg
2                                                 elementary
```

I thought it might need to have to be a lot of nested ifelse strings. It goes up to 14 columns, and the new "grades" column will need to be diverse enough to address any combination of grades (e.g. 6 - 12).

I'm trying to create a new column based on the values of already existing columns. Those existing columns are all YES and NO (like checkmarks). I want the new column to reflect categories that bin together the YES values. Say, one row has YES in the "ninth", "tenth", "eleventh" and "twelfth" column, I want that to translate into "high school" in the new column.

Comment: Hi. Your question is a bit unclear. 

- (I) Can you provide a small example that people can replicate? 
- (II) What is that new column you want to, the words you write in there hare different from the names of the data frame you defined first. 
- (III) Is the column supposed to be a new column of the same data.frame?

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm trying to create a new column based on the values of already existing columns. Those existing columns are all YES and NO (like checkmarks). I want the new column to reflect categories that bin together the YES values. 

Say, one row has YES in the "ninth", "tenth", "eleventh" and "twelfth" column, I want that to translate into "high school" in the new column.

Comment: Great! Please add that description to your question above by editing it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call apply-like function on each row of dataframe with multiple arguments from each row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15059076/call-apply-like-function-on-each-row-of-dataframe-with-multiple-arguments-from-e)

Comment: The new column needs to be original categories (like "elementary" or "high school")

 Yes the column is supposed to be of the data.frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `apply` with `MARGIN =1` to loop over the rows

```
df1$Grades <-  apply(df1, 1, FUN = function(x) {
      i1 <- x=="yes"
      if(any(i1[-(1:2)])) "elementary" else toString(tolower(names(df1)[i1]))})
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(PreK = c("yes", "no"), Kindergarten = c("yes", 
"no"), First = c("no", "yes"), Second = c("no", "yes"), Third = c("no", 
"yes"), Fourth = c("no", "yes")), .Names = c("PreK", "Kindergarten", 
"First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c("1", "2"))
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a try!