# How to apply ggplot2 to each row in a data frame

Tags: r, ggplot2, apply

I want to code a `ggplot2` visualization as a function, and then `apply` the function on each row of a dataframe (I want to use `apply` to avoid a `for` loop, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31994539/5535152).)

The data:

```r
library(ggplot2)
point1 <- c(1,2)
point2 <- c(2,2)

points <-as.data.frame(rbind(point1,point2))
```

I saved `points` as a data frame and it runs fine in `ggplot2`:

```r
ggplot(data = points) +
    geom_point(aes(x = points[, 1], y = points[, 2])) +
    xlim(-3, 3) +
    ylim(-3, 3) +
    theme_bw()
```

[image]

That's not really the plot I want though: I would like *two plots*, each one with one point.

Now I build a function that will loop through the rows of the data frame:

```r
plot_data <- function(data) {
  ggplot(data) +
    geom_point(aes(x = data[, 1], y = data[, 2])) +
    xlim(-3, 3) +
    ylim(-3, 3) +
    theme_bw()
}
```

I create a list to store the plots:

```
myplots <- list()
```

And here is the call to `apply`, following [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5330217/5535152):

```
myplots <- apply(points, 1, plot_data)
```

But I get the following error:

```
#> Error: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, 
not a numeric vector
```

But my data *are* a data frame.

Is this because: "`apply()` will try to convert the data.frame into a matrix (see the help docs). If it does not gracefully convert due to mixed data types, I'm not quite sure what would result" as noted in a comment to [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5330217/5535152) I referred to?

Still, if I check the data class after the call to apply, the data are still a dataframe:

```
class(points)
#> [1] "data.frame"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: `apply` is a poor choice here. `apply` is built to work on matrices, and when you give `apply` a data frame, the very first thing it does is convert it to a matrix--as you say. This conversion is within the `apply` function. Your original data is still a data frame and still unchanged (unless you assign something to it, `points <- apply(...)`. So, if you *really* want to use `apply`, you can convert the vector row of the matrix that `apply` works with back to a data frame, but this is quite inefficient.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. What would you recommend, as an alternative to `apply`?

Comment: If you're allergic to for loop and open to other `*apply` family functions, you could  use `lapply` across the row indexes, something like `myplots <- lapply(1:nrow(points), function(i) plot_data(points[i, ]))`. Or a for loop, `for(i in 1:nrow(points)) {myplots[[i]] <- plot_data(points[i, ])}`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. I tried `lapply` before, but what confused me is that reading the syntax `lapply(X, FUN, …)`, I thought (1) that `X` should be the data (meaning the whole data.frame) and (2) that I would just need to call `plot_data` in place of `FUN`. Where I can learn more about the construction you used?

Comment: I don't really know a good source for info on that construction... it's more just familiarity with `*apply` family functions and R data structures. I really like [this FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3505701/903061) for understanding the *apply family functions generally. And of course the R for Data Science [chapter on iteration](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/iteration.html) is good, and includes an introduction to `purrr`'s variants of these functions.

Comment: Whatever `X` is is what `lapply` will iterate over, and because data frames are built as lists of columns, if you `lapply(some_data_frame, foo)` the iteration will be over columns. E.g., `lapply(mtcars,mean)`, `lapply(iris, class)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by [Gregor Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/903061/gregor-thomas) in the comment:

```r
library(ggplot2)
point1 <- c(1, 2)
point2 <- c(2, 2)

points <- as.data.frame(rbind(point1, point2))

plot_data <- function(data) {
  ggplot(data) +
    geom_point(aes(x = data[, 1], y = data[, 2])) +
    xlim(-3, 3) +
    ylim(-3, 3) +
    theme_bw()
}
myplots <- list()
myplots <- lapply(1:nrow(points), function(i) plot_data(points[i, ]))
myplots
#> [[1]]
```

[image]

```
#> 
#> [[2]]
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-04-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: you don't need `myplots <- list()` when using lapply. If you have data that is separated by row, why don't you arrange it in a list in a first place? You can then easier loop over the list with all the apply functions and purrr and many more. I'd create a list by splitting your data frame by rows and then iterate over each data frame.