# R apply custom vectorised function to row in dataframe, specific columns

Tags: r, dataframe, apply

This should be simple but I just can't get the `apply` to communicate with my vectorised function.

Test data is: `df <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b1 = c(4:5, NA), b2 = c(5,6,5))`
Looks like this:

```
  a b1 b2
1 1  4  5
2 2  5  6
3 3 NA  5
```

Custom function checks returns a vector to indicate whether values fall in a given interval.

```
validScore <- function(x, a, b) {
  is.na(x) == FALSE &
  x%%1 == 0 &
  findInterval(x, c(a,b), rightmost.closed = TRUE) == 1
}
```

Test of custom function: `validScore(c(3, 3.5, 6, NA), 1, 5)` returns the logical vector `TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE` as expected.

I want to run the custom function on the row defined by the columns b1 and b2. This would return TRUE FALSE FALSE (that is T on (b1=4,b2=5), F on (b1=5,b2=6) and F on (b1=NA,b2=5)).

The answer [Call apply-like function on each row of dataframe with multiple arguments from each row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15059076/r-how-to-call-apply-like-function-on-each-row-of-dataframe-with-multiple-argum) for selecting the columns, and [how to apply a function to every row of a matrix (or a data frame) in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236368/how-to-apply-a-function-to-every-row-of-a-matrix-or-a-data-frame-in-r) together suggest the following:

```
library(dplyr)
apply(select(df, b1:b2), 1, function(x) validScore(x, 1, 5))
```

but that doesn't actually send the row to the function, instead assessing each value individually, so output is:

```
   [,1]  [,2]  [,3]
b1 TRUE  TRUE FALSE
b2 TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

Sticking a rowwise() into the middle like `select(df, b1:b2) %>% rowwise() %>% apply(1, function(x) validScore(x, 1, 5))` makes no difference.

I thought it might by something to do with the form that the dplyr select returned, but `apply(df[, c("b1", "b2")], 1, function(x) validScore(x, 1, 5))` also generates the same result.

Comment: this function works on one x at a time so you will need to combine them after or you will get a matrix like you show, use `all` or `rowSums`/`colSums`: `rowSums(Vectorize(validScore)(df[, -1], 1, 5)) > 1`

Comment: yes @rawr, you (and @csgillespie) are correct. I am using the validScore function in two different ways and that is the conflict. I originally wrote it to identify which scores were invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `dplyr` or `plyr`. You can just use base R.

The first thing to do is to make `validScore` return only a single `TRUE` or `FALSE`. This can be done using the `all` function

```
validScore <- function(x, a, b) {
  test = is.na(x) == FALSE &
    x %% 1 == 0 &
    findInterval(x, c(a,b), rightmost.closed = TRUE) == 1
  all(test)
}
```

After that just use the standard `apply`

```
## Select columns 2 & 3 
apply(df[, 2:3], 1, validScore, a=1, b=8)
```

Comment: thanks, yes. Your solution has made me realise that I may be using validScore in two (incompatible) ways.

Comment: There's still something wrong here. Testing with `apply(df[, 2:3], 1, validScore, a=1, b=5)` gets `FALSE FALSE FALSE` but should be TFF

Comment: Sorry, I made a change to validScore Works now

Comment: Does indeed. And it also worked when I made the adjustments to the real code in light of my incompatible function problem.