# How to create binary matrix from numerical matrix in R?

Tags: r, matrix, binary

Pseudocode for matrix operation that I try to find out

1. If matrix cell value < alpha, put 1.
2. Else 0.

---

I want to create a binary matrix with the alpha from p-value matrix `p.mat` but I cannot handle `apply` correctly where I try satisfy the pseudocode.

**First approach**

```
# http://stackoverflow.com/a/4236383/54964
new <- apply(p.mat.p, 1, function(x) 
   if (alpha > x) {
      x <- 0
   } else {
      x <- 1
   }
)
```

**Second approach but fails**

```
new <- apply(p.mat.p, 1, function(x)
  x <- (x < alpha)
)
print(new)
#Error in match.fun(FUN) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default
#Calls: apply -> match.fun
#Execution halted
```

**Trial and Code**

```
library("psych")

ids <- seq(1,11)
M.cor <- cor(mtcars)
colnames(M.cor) <- ids
rownames(M.cor) <- ids

p.mat <- psych::corr.test(M.cor, adjust = "none", ci = F)

p.mat.p <- p.mat[["p"]]

alpha <- .00000005

# http://stackoverflow.com/a/4236383/54964
new <- apply(p.mat.p, 1, function(x) 
   if (alpha > x) {
      x <- 0
   } else {
      x <- 1
   }
)

#Error in alpha > x : 
#  comparison (6) is possible only for atomic and list types
#Calls: sapply -> lapply -> FUN
#Execution halted
```

**Example** with a square matrix and a p-value for alpha.

*Input: nxn matrix with a p-value* = `p.mat.p`

```
 # str(p.mat.p)
 num [1:11, 1:11] 0.00 4.04e-09 1.09e-09 4.32e-06 1.78e-05 ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:11] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:11] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...


 #              1            2            3            4            5
#1  0.000000e+00 4.037623e-09 1.091445e-09 4.322152e-06 1.780708e-05
#2  4.037623e-09 0.000000e+00 1.659424e-09 5.625666e-07 5.174268e-05
#3  1.091445e-09 1.659424e-09 0.000000e+00 1.304240e-05 4.935086e-06
...
```

*Expected output: nxn binary matrix of ones and zeros, alpha=0.2 and the intended output is*

```
      [,1] [,2]  [,3] [,4]  [,5]
[1,] FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE
[2,]  TRUE TRUE  TRUE TRUE  TRUE
[3,]  TRUE TRUE  TRUE TRUE  TRUE
```

R: 3.3.1
OS: Debian 8.5

Comment: Can you give input matrix plus the alpha value and then the intended output matrix? I am not sure whether you are just looking for some floor/ceiling function.

Comment: `as.numeric(your_matrix < your_alpha)`.

Comment: Works fine for me using your trial code. Try again in a new R session.

Comment: @Masi, Gregor's suggestion will work with `p.mat.p`. I guess what has happened  is that you hadn't defined `alpha` before trying the inequality. ie try `p.mat.p < beta`  (or `p.mat.p < mean`, or other function) to reproduce your error from your comment, and then try `beta=1 ; p.mat.p < beta`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do

```
alpha <- .00000005
p.mat.p <- (p.mat.p < alpha)
str(p.mat.p)
print(p.mat.p)
```

Output

```
 logi [1:11, 1:11] TRUE TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE ...
 - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  ..$ : chr [1:11] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  ..$ : chr [1:11] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
       1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    11
1   TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
2   TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
3   TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
4  FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
5  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
6   TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
7  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
8  FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
9  FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
10 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
11 FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```