# Sparklyr : Trying to access the elements of a vector stored in a column using an exterior variable as index

Tags: r, sparklyr

I have asked the very same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51088748/dplyr-trying-to-access-the-elements-of-a-vector-stored-in-a-column-using-an-ex) and got a nice answer for dplyr but now I want to do the same on sparklyr.

So I have a spark dataframe where one of the columns contains vectors/lists. I'd like to create a column that contain the element of the vector with index i (an exterior variable).

e.g. with i = 2

[link to data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyZSY.png)

In dplyr the solution is:

```
data <- data %>%
  mutate(element = sapply(list_x, "[", i))
```

But this doesn't work in sparklyr as `sapply` doesn't exist in sparklyr.

Comment: Without providing the structure, it is difficult to comment.  Did you convert to spark dataset, like `iris_tbl <- copy_to(sc, iris)`;  What is `data`?

Comment: Yes, data is a spark dataframe. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: Without knowing how data is created (what is its Spark type) it is hard to answer. While dput might not be a good option for Spark dataframes you should provide some form of reproducible example.