# Optimizing R for loop for speed

Tags: r, function, performance, optimization

I have the following function I need to run through a dataset of 150000 rows and need to speed it up. I am already using future_lapply for multi-core processing as well as cmpfun to compile the function but is there anything else that can be done?

```
execution_strategy_export <- function(data) {
  
  data$outside_business_hours <- NA
  data$trigger_period <- NA
  data$trigger_time <- NA
  data$post_period_two <- NA
  data$result <- NA
  data$adjusted_count <- NA
  
  for (i in 1:(nrow(data))) {  # Changed to nrow(data) - 1 to avoid unnecessary checks
    
    # Extract values for this iteration
    today_period_one_close <- data[i, "close"]
    today_loss_interval <- data[i, "loss_interval"]
    today_ref_rate <- data[i, "ref_rate"]
    today_period_one_high <- data[i, "high"]
    
    today_adjusted_interval <- data[i, "adjustment_interval"]
    today_adjusted_count <- floor((today_period_one_high - today_ref_rate) / today_adjusted_interval)
    
    pd_max_period_one <- today_ref_rate + (today_adjusted_interval * today_adjusted_count) - today_loss_interval
    
    IF1 <- 0
    
    if (data[i, "hour"] < 8 || data[i, "hour"] > 17) {
      
      data[i, "outside_business_hours"] <- "Excl"
      
    } else {
      
      period_one <- data[i, "period_one"]
      
      if (period_one > 0) {
        
        data[i, "trigger_period"] <- 1
        data[i, "trigger_time"] <- data[i, "time"]
        
      } else {
        
        j <- i + 1
        
        while (j <= nrow(data)) {
          
          # Extract values for the j-th row
          today_open_j <- data[j, "open"]
          today_high_j <- data[j, "high"]
          today_low_j <- data[j, "low"]
          today_close_j <- data[j, "close"]
          
          input_dbl <- (today_period_one_close - today_ref_rate) / today_adjusted_interval
          close_ref_rate_adjusted_count <- ifelse(today_period_one_close > today_ref_rate, floor(input_dbl), ceiling(input_dbl))
          prior_period_close_SL <- today_ref_rate + (today_adjusted_interval * close_ref_rate_adjusted_count) - today_loss_interval
          
          input_dbl_up <- (today_high_j - today_ref_rate) / today_adjusted_interval
          today_adjusted_count <- max(today_adjusted_count, floor(input_dbl_up))
          today_max <- today_ref_rate + (today_adjusted_interval * today_adjusted_count) - today_loss_interval
          
          if (today_open_j < pd_max_period_one || (today_low_j < today_max || today_close_j < today_max)) {
            
            IF1 <- ifelse(today_open_j < pd_max_period_one, min(prior_period_close_SL, pd_max_period_one), today_max)
            
            data[i, "adjusted_count"] <- j - i + 1
            
          }
          
          data[i, "trigger_period"] <- j - i + 1
          
          ifelse(data[i, "trigger_period"] > 1 && (i + data[i, "trigger_period"]) <= nrow(data),
                 data[i, "trigger_time"] <- data[i + data[i, "trigger_period"] - 1, "time"],
                 data[i, "trigger_time"] <- data[i, "time"])
          
          if (IF1 > 0) {
            
            break
            
          }
          
          j <- j + 1
          
        }
      }
    }
    
    data[i, "post_period_two"] <- IF1
    
    data[i, "result"] <- data[i, "period_one"] + IF1
    
    data[i, "adjusted_count"] <- today_adjusted_count
  }
  return(data)
}
```

I tried using data.tables to improve the speed but struggling to recode the function due to its complexity

Comment: Did you consider using apply? - https://stackoverflow.com/q/4236368/680068

Comment: Did you do a [profiling](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/perf-measure.html#profiling) what takes most time? Also, for your parallel processing, it seems that you always load the complete data set to every core instead of just providing the subset needed, which can also slow things down

Comment: @zx8754 OP’s data seems to be a data.frames, so `apply` would be the wrong tool (it converts the input to a matrix which converts all column types to one common type).

Comment: Without data or explanation, It's rather obscure to me what the function actually does but it seems likely that its efficiency could be improved. There are quite a few places which don't make much sense to me, e.g. testing for `data[i, "trigger_period"] > 1` after `data[i, "trigger_period"] <- j - i + 1`: we know that `j > i` so this will always be true. Some assignments you have in your `while` do not depend on `j` (`input_dbl` and the two below) so they can be moved on level higher and not be repeated so often.

Comment: Also, at the end with `data[i, "adjusted_count"] <- today_adjusted_count` you overwrite what you might have changed with `data[i, "adjusted_count"] <- j - i + 1` in your `while` loop. I think it would be worth to think thoroughly again about the problem you are trying to solve and maybe start from scratch.

Comment: I agree with both of @RobertHacken's comments.  You have shown us *how* you are trying to solve your problem, but you have not told us *what* your problem actually is.  It may well be that your data format is inefficient and the optimal solution wwould be to reformat your data frame to make processing it easier/faster.  But we simply don't know.  But one thing is almost certainly true:  "If you're using a for loop in R, there's probably a better way to do it"...

Comment: @KonradRudolph if dealing with a data frame and you want an `apply`-like approach, would you use a `pmap` variant, or a different approach altogether such as recoding the function to be vectorised in the first place?

Comment: @PaulStaffordAllen In the first instance I would try very hard to transform the table into normal/“tidy” data so that I could use the standard ‘dplyr’ verbs. If that is impractical for some reason I would go via `Map`/`pmap`.

Answer (score 0):

#### Few things to try:

1. Don't use strings, String comparison is inefficient. Declare some sort of enum and use it instead. (Thus replacing all the string manipulations with integers.)
2. Instead of `today_period_one_close <- data[i, "close"]` do the whole manipulation first: `today_period_one_close = data[, "close"]` or potentially if your data format allows it `today_period_one_close = data$close`

   - Vector operations are faster due to R optimizations(called vectorization, which calls underlying C libraries)
   - There are also some potential concerns about the way memory is accessed but that is likely too small to matter.
   - Then do the iteration over these vectors instead of the whole table - it appears you don't need it all that much.
3. I would do the whole exclusion of data outside business hours outside of the loop - unless you for some reason need them anyways. It seems that you're only ever accessing lines i and i+1 if I'm reading the stuff correctly but I'm unsure about what it means and why is that.
4. If this isn't enough, do Rprof to see where your code spends most time.
5. Rewriting critical part in Rcpp could speed up the code by ~200 times if my memory serves correctly. It's been a while since I last optimized R code.
6. Don't bother with future_lapply. Usually not necessary if you structure your code vector-friendly. Can't say much about cmpfun, it will be likely some sort of middle ground between Rcpp and R.

All in all, 150000 lines is perfectly manageable size if you manage to avoid most of the usual R pitfalls. R isn't exactly a fast language.

Posting a sample of your data would help for reproduction purposes.

Comment: Reader's note for those only familar with R - enum here probably means factor.  Is that a fair substitution, @Shamis?

Comment: Mostly yes. I'm not too fond of factors, I would argue that doing some "integers as enum" shenanigans could be justifiable in this case.